# Parse HTML contents of Webview - Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I'd like to detect when my webview loads a certain page, for example, an incorrect login page.  I've tried using `onLoadResource` and `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`, but I can't get either to work, and I'm thinking a better way would to parse the HTML whenever the webview starts loading a page, and if a certain string is found within the HTML, then do whatever.

Is there a method to do this?  I've tried using TagSoup, but I have no clue how to relate it into my webview.  Here's what my code looks like now:

```
String fullpost = "pass=" + passwordt + "&user=" + usernamet + "&uuid=" + UUID;

    String url = "mydomain.com";
        mWebview.postUrl(url, EncodingUtils.getBytes(fullpost, "BASE64"));
        mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            public void onPageFinished(WebView mWebview, String url) {
                String webUrl = mWebview.getUrl();
                    if (webUrl.contains("/loginf")) {
                        MainActivity.this.mWebview.stopLoading();
                        MainActivity.this.setContentView(R.layout.preweb);

                    }
              }
       });
```

Basically, the postUrl is initiated from a user click on a button in a layout, and that's what starts the WebView, and then I call `setContentView` to the layout that contains the webview.

From there, if the login info is correct, the webpage goes to XXX, and if it's incorrect, it goes to YYY.  So, I want to detect immediately (and on every page load from there on out), if YYY is loaded, then `//domagic`.  Hope that makes sense.  Being the page redirect from `url` to XXX or YYY is automatic and not initiated by the user, `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` doesn't work, and I can't figure out how to use `onLoadResource`, so I'm just completely lost.

My current thought is loading everything in a separate thread and then using the WebView to display the content (that way I can parse the HTML), but I'm not sure how that'd work or even how to do it.

Anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've read a way to get a text string of a webview's content. Then, you could use jsoup to parse it. [neh, don't even need jsoup; just indexOf string check]

I'll suggest that you do consider handling the login with an HTTP client. It gives you flexibility, and seems the more proper way to go. I've been using the loopj library for HTTP get and post requests. It allows for simpler code. For me, anyway, a relative Android newbie. Here's some code from my project, to get you thinking. I've left out stuff like progress bar, and cookie management.

```
private void loginFool() {
    String urlString = "http://www.example.com/login/";

    // username & password
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.put("username", username.getText().toString());
    params.put("password", password.getText().toString());

    // send the request
    loopjClient.post(urlString, params, new TextHttpResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            // called before request is started
            //System.err.println("Starting...");
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString) {
            // called when response HTTP status is "200 OK"

            // see if 'success' was a failed login...
            int idx = responseString.indexOf("Please try again!");
            if(idx > -1) {
                makeMyToast("Sorry, login failed!");
            }
            // or actual success-ful login
            else {

               // manage cookies here 

               // put extractData in separate thread 
                final String responseStr = responseString;
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run(){

                        extractData(responseStr);
                        selectData(defaultPrefs.getInt("xyz_display_section", 0));

                        // start the next activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PageViewActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();

                    }
                }).start();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
            // called when response HTTP status is "4XX" (eg. 401, 403, 404)

            makeMyToast("Whoops, network error!");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // done
        }

    });
}
```

You can see that, in the response handler's onSuccess callback, I can test for a string, to see if the login failed, and, in the onFailure callback, I give a network error message.

I'm not experienced enough to know what percent of web servers this type of post login works on.

The loopj client receives and manages cookies. If you will be accessing pages from the site via a webview you need to copy cookies from the loopj client, over to the webview. I cobbled code from a few online posts, to do that:

```
// get cookies from the generic http session, and copy them to the webview
CookieSyncManager.createInstance(getApplicationContext());
CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookie();
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();

List<Cookie> cookies = xyzCookieStore.getCookies();
for (Cookie eachCookie : cookies) {
    String cookieString = eachCookie.getName() + "=" + eachCookie.getValue();
    cookieManager.setCookie("http://www.example.com", cookieString);
    //System.err.println(">>>>> " + "cookie: " + cookieString);
}
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
// holy crap, it worked; I am automatically logged in, in the webview
```

EDIT: And, I should have included the class variable definitions and initializations:

```
private AsyncHttpClient loopjClient = new AsyncHttpClient();
private PersistentCookieStore xyzCookieStore;

xyzCookieStore = new PersistentCookieStore(this);
loopjClient.setCookieStore(Utility.xyzCookieStore);
```